# The exact limitation of request from one IP

Tags: facebook, request, ip, limit

I'm developing the application which gets the top 20 of pages from all letters. Basically, at this time there's no problem with limitation. But I need to know what's the exact number of requests from one IP address per second ?

Best regards,

Comment: I don't understand the question. The maximum load depends upon many factors (network bandwith & latency, computer power, memory, operating system...)

Comment: Facebook themselves impose a request limit

Comment: I know about hardware limitation. But I need to know how many requests I can make from one IP address per second to the facebook web-site ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exact number per second. Like any other site, if you do too many you will likely get blocked as a denial of service attack. If you are doing too many of an extended period of time, Facebook will likely block you, at least temporarily.

If you are trying to crawl Facebook, then you should obey the rules defined in their robots.txt file like any other crawler/spider should.

https://www.facebook.com/robots.txt

http://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

That said, I've done around 15 million update requests per day back when they have profile boxes. Never had a problem.